# View of onClick method returns null when cast to TextView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the integer value of a TextView when it is clicked. For this I am using onClick attribute of the XML file.
Here is my XML code:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/o1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="check"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is the check method:

```
public void check(View v) {

    TextView c= (TextView) v;
    int z = Integer.parseInt(c.getText().toString());
    // more code here
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
 10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    ... 9 more
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "518 "
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    at com.project.project.MainActivity.check(MainActivity.java:69)
10-30 20:16:47.952: E/AndroidRuntime(12427):    ... 11 more
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Invalid int: "518 "
```

contains a space. Use `trim()` before calling `parseInt()`

```
 int z = Integer.parseInt(c.getText().toString().trim());
```